# Unity: How do I reference a variable from another script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How do I reference a variable from another script? I am new and have been working on this for over twenty hours and I am super frustrated. I have tried many things and could not get it to do what I needed. I would greatly appreciate any kind of help. I either need to see how to reference the variable from the first script or how to access the variable from the method in the first script.

//Heres the first script.

```
public class Key : MonoBehaviour {
public bool fireCode;

public void fcodeOff()
{
 fireCode = false;
} 
}
```

//Heres the second script

```
public class FireTRAP : MonoBehaviour 
{ 
public Key script;

void Update(){
script.fcodeOff();

}
```

This is where I get confused and not sure what to do. I can use script.fcodeOff(); in update and it is using the method from the other script but I need to reference the fireCode variable or the fireCode variable in that method.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank You,

Comment: Assign the key script to the firetrap public variable. Just like any other component

Comment: If you have an instance of `Key` (which you do in your `FireTRAP` -> `script`), then you can use that to access the `fireCode` bool. You should be able to try `script.fireCode = true;` to set `fireCode` to true, in your `FireTRAP` class.

Comment: Essentially, you are already doing what you are asking when you call `script.fcodeOff();`

Comment: Perhaps this will help you: https://www.w3schools.com/cs/cs_intro.php

Comment: Something to note, Unity is using C#, so although you may be making a game in Unity, you will probably need to know C# to make it successful. When you are talking about `Script`s, they are really just `object`s. So interactions between them (property retrieval, calling methods, accessing instance variables) would be the same as any other `object`s in C#.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what you are doing just by those 2 blocks of code.

Are you attaching the script or object from the Unity Game Engine into the serialized field in the inspector for your fire trap class?

If you aren't you should be instantiating your script class

```cs
public class FireTRAP : MonoBehaviour 
{ 
    public Key script;

    void Start(){

        Key = new Script();

    }

    void Update(){
        script.fcodeOff();

    }
```

Doing it this way you should be able to reference the fireCode variable just by calling `Key.fireCode`

```cs
    void Update(){
        Debug.Log(Key.fireCode);
    }
```

Should print `false` to the Debug Console.